# Checkbox is NOT check on click (React)

Tags: html, reactjs

I created a todo list by using react. I get some problem that I want to create checkbox but my checkbox it does not work and I cannot solve :( I don't know what's wrong with that.

I set the data for each task and then I need to change the completed of some task, but it cannot click and change the completed task

This is my code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: todoData,
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if(todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
          // console.log(todo.completed)
        }
        return todo
      })
      return {
        todos: updatedTodos
      }
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    const todoItem = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} 
      handleChange={this.handleChange}/>)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="header">My Todo Lists</h1>
        {todoItem}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```
function TodoItem(props) {
    let textItem = props.item.completed === true ? 
        <del>{props.item.text}</del> : props.item.text
    return (
        <div className="list">
            <input 
                type="checkbox"
                checked={props.item.completed}
                onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)} 
            />
            <p className="item">{textItem}</p>
        </div>
   
    )
}
```

And this is my data

```
const todoData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Practice coding",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Grocery shopping",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Wash the dishes",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "Take out the trash",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: "Teach my brother homework",
        completed: false
    }
]
```

Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like on your `handleChange` you are mutating the existing state on your `map` transformation. you must return a new state instead.

Replace your `handleChange` with the following code:

```js
handleChange(id) {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map((todo) => {
      return {
        ...todo,
        completed: todo.id === id ? !todo.completed : todo.completed
      };
    });
    return {
      todos: updatedTodos
    };
  });
}
```